# Validating User Entry, Loop Never Satisfied? (Python 3.2.1.1)

Tags: validation, loops, while-loop, user-input, infinite-loop

**Thank you in advance to anyone who helps.**

I am using this code to validate user entry for a program I am writing however the **WHILE** loop is never satisfied by the user entry and I am unable to understand why.

```
User_Answer = input('Which is the correct answer A,B,C or D?' ).upper()
#Ask user which they believe correct and save it as variable with the identifier User_Answer

while User_Answer != 'A' and User_Answer !='B' and User_Answer !='C' and User_Answer !='D': 
    User_Answer = input('Which is the correct answer A,B,C or D?' ).upper()
# Is user entry valid in the form of A,B,C or D and re-asks question if not. 

else:
    do something
```

Comment: I can see a few issues. I don't know what language you're using, but one time you call upper without and then with brackets. I'm going out on a limb here, but that could be part of your problem. Then there seems to be a stray `else`, I'm assuming the first `else` lost it's `if` friend while getting pasted here.

Comment: Thanks, I am using python, the first .upper is an error when copying from my program there is () after the .upper in my code. I changed the else but it did not make a difference.